# Where to buy dust cap for bottom bracket for an old bicycle?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I need to buy replacement dust cap for the bottom bracket in the picture. Is it still available anywhere? Under what name can it be found?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please confirm, do you mean the thingie in the centre of your photo? That is not a pedal, that is a crank installed on an axle that runs through a bottom bracket fixed using a cotter pin.

Comment: You might need to make one from something like acetyl/delrin by turning it on a lathe.  I doubt such a thing is still available retail new.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a dust cap on a cottered crank.

Comment: I adopted a lid from 1 gallon bottle, but its so cheap looking that i rather not use it.

Comment: So you're looking for caps for the bottom bracket.

Comment: Did you try a web search? Just searching for "crank dust cap" gets me many, many hits, the second one being eBay listing for the correct part.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt you would be able to find replacement for a bottom bracket dust cap on a bicycle which looks that old.
The economics for such parts do not make sense in general.

Something you could do, however, is 3D print it. It is a fun little project to redesign a part in 3D. You can use something like SketchUp to do it.
It will be a bit expensive though to have it printed (~tens of $), but you get to pick between different polymers.

FYI It is something I did to salvage a 1960s chest of drawers I have, where the plastic bits holding it together had become completely brittle.